# Updating MySQL table with only unique records?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am googling around and reading posts on this site but not clear what I should I do go with insert unique, records.

I basically have a giant file that that has a single column of data in it that needs to be imported into a db table where several thousand of the records from my text file already exist.

There are no id's in the text file I need to import and what I am reading insert ignore looks to be solving for duplicate ID's. I want new ids created for any of the new records added but obviously I can't have duplicates.

This would ideally be done with load data infile...but really not sure:

Insert IGNORE?
ON Duplicate Key?

Comment: I would personally just read in the whole file, and then remove duplicates once it has been loaded into the MySQL database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you add this as an answer? This is probably the best approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to read in the entire file using `LOAD DATA`, and then insert all non duplicates into the table which already exists.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'large_file.txt' INTO TABLE new_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(name);
```

This assumes that the first line of your giant file does *not* contain a column header.  If it does, then you can add `IGNORE 1 LINES` to the statement above.

You can now `INSERT` the names in `new_table` into your already-existing table using `INSERT INTO IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO your_table_archive (name)
SELECT name
FROM new_table
```

Any duplicate records which MySQL encounters will *not* be inserted, and instead the original ones will be retained.  And you can drop `new_table` once you have what you need from it.

Comment: Ok cool...my only question is about adding the (ID) in the last line of your example. Is that indicating how unique is defined? The column I am importing is 'name'...and that single column is all that is in the file. Deleting them afterwards: how would I make sure that I keep the records that already exist in the db vs deleting them in favor of the new?

Comment: The `(ID)` is naming the column you are reading in.  I have changed it to `name`.  With regard to deleting "afterwards"...since you are reading in a single, column, it should not matter which duplicate you retain, unless there is another angle of this question which you never told us.

Comment: I believe it will matter though because the names table is linked to a bunch of other tables ...specifically join tables where the old id's are important. Thoughts? Clear on your first point. thank you!!